# Unknown C# Error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi I don't know why C# is having a parsing error on my last Curly Bracket, sorry if it is very simple im new to C# here is the code.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string IP = "192.168.0.8";
    public int Port = "25001";

    void OnGUI()
    {
        if(Network.peerType == NetworkPeerType.Disconnected)
        {
            if (GUI.Button(new Rect(100,100,100,25),"Join Existing Server"))
            {
                Network.Connect(Ip,Port);    
            }

            if (GUI.Button(new Rect(100,125,100,25),"Create New Server"))
            {
                Network.InitializeServer(10,Port);
                //First Number Above next to port in perenthisies is number of allowed clients / 1x Server (# of players allowed to join game.)
            }
            else 
            {
                if(Network.peerType == NetworkPeerType.Client)    
                {
                    GUI.Label(new Rect(100,100,100,25),"Client");
                    if(GUI.Button (new Rect(100,125,100,25),"Disconnect"))
                    {
                        Network.Disconnect(250);
                    }
                }
                if(Network.peerType == NetworkPeerType.Server)
                {
                    GUI.Label(new Rect(100,100,100,25),"Server");
                    GUI.Label(new Rect(100,125,100,25),"Connections: " + Network.connections.Length);

                    if(GUI.Button (new Rect(100,125,100,25),"Disconnect"))
                    {
                        Network.Disconnect(250);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The last "}" is coming up red any help would be appreciated thanks!

Just so people don;t get confused it is supposed to be a server and client for an on-line video game but it won't let me run the game with the error. I have tried to improve the formatting and remove blank space but none seemed to work, I have also made sure that there are the right amount of closing bracket at the end of the code so I have no Idea what is wrong.

Comment: If last `}` is coming red, then you have incorrect number of braces. Just verify them one by one and check that each opening braces matches closing one

Comment: If you get this error, simply add a } and try to autoformat your file. In Visual Studio this is Ctrl+k then Ctrl+d

Comment: I hope the code you have here is the same one you have on your IDE. You just added the brace `}` after `Network.Disconnect(250);` after @Klaus gave his answer so I cant help wondering

Answer (score 7):

Add a closing bracket after:

```
if(GUI.Button (new Rect(100,125,100,25),"Disconnect"))
{

    Network.Disconnect(250);
```

It's missing.

Comment: That caused another error saying cannot implicitly convert type string to int?

Comment: @user3244340 that's another problem altogether. You should probably post a new question about that error if don't know how to fix it. Look at the line number and make sure to indicate the line that has the error, so that people can more easily help you.

Comment: @user3244340 Regarding the other problem: Loose the double quotes here: `public int Port = "25001";` should be `public int Port = 25001;`

Comment: @GrantWinney questions regarding compilation errors should show the original code posted by the OP, not re-formatted code. Furthermore you made no effort to explain your edit, and you rendered my answer wrong, after I had posted it.

Answer (score 3):

After formatting your code, I can see you're missing one final closing brace.

Add a closing brace `}` at the very end of your code snippet above.

Comment: That caused another error saying cannot implicitly convert type string to int?

Comment: @user3244340 That is a different issue due to this line: `public int Port = "25001";`

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate the question is not to do with this, but just to help, the error regarding:

> cannot implicitly convert type string to int

can be solved by changing your code to the following:

```
public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public string IP = "192.168.0.8";
    public string Port = "25001";
```

or

```
public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public string IP = "192.168.0.8";
    public int Port = 25001;
```

Comment: @user3244340 If you open a new question, we can help you with the other errors. But be sure to give it a good go first mind - it is great practice!

Answer (score 0):

This is your code with correction. Be careful about the brackets.

```
using UnityEngine;

using System.Collections;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {

public string IP = "192.168.0.8";
    public int Port = "25001";

    void OnGUI()
    {

        if(Network.peerType == NetworkPeerType.Disconnected)
        {

            if (GUI.Button(new Rect(100,100,100,25),"Join Existing Server"))
            {

            Network.Connect(Ip,Port);   

            }



            if (GUI.Button(new Rect(100,125,100,25),"Create New Server"))
            {

            Network.InitializeServer(10,Port);
                //First Number Above next to port in perenthisies is number of allowed clients / 1x Server (# of players allowed to join game.)

            }

            else 
            {

            if(Network.peerType == NetworkPeerType.Client)  
                {


                    GUI.Label(new Rect(100,100,100,25),"Client");
                    if(GUI.Button (new Rect(100,125,100,25),"Disconnect"))
                    {

                        Network.Disconnect(250);


                    }


                }
                if(Network.peerType == NetworkPeerType.Server)
                {

                    GUI.Label(new Rect(100,100,100,25),"Server");
                    GUI.Label(new Rect(100,125,100,25),"Connections: " + Network.connections.Length);

                    if(GUI.Button (new Rect(100,125,100,25),"Disconnect"))
                    {

                        Network.Disconnect(250);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```